# I accidentally deleted the admin's token

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2

I'm using Influx 2.0 (https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/) and after creating the admin user with `influx setup`, I accidentally deleted the admin's token and don't know how to restore it. No created token has all privileges, so it's not as simple as creating a new token, even with "All Access Token" write:users and read:users is missing. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: I asked on Influxdb GitHub and they are addressing the issue in the next release: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/22706

Answer (score 0):

InfluxDB typically uses an operator token as initial and most powerful token. If you deleted that, you should be able to generate a new one (that you can use to authenticate to generate more restricting tokens) with the following command:
[influxd recovery auth create-operator](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/reference/cli/influxd/recovery/auth/create-operator/)